# yii disable onclick behaviour in CGridView when clicking a row

Tags: yii

Seems like the default behaviour in CGridView is that when someone clicks on the row, it adds the "selected" class to that row. How do I get rid of that? When clicking the row, I don't want anything to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the `$selectableRows` property to `0`:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'selectableRows' => 0,
  /*the rest of your initialization properties*/
)); ?>
```

[You can see it in Yii Class Reference.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView/#selectableRows-detail)

Comment: Thank you! Been looking for this forever!